# Как реализовать круговое меню?

Tags: android, java

Как в андроиде сделеть круговое меню ([пример](https://34e83aad3cc68240db38d20b071c408cb1f077fd.googledrive.com/host/0B8X6tTe_EasFM1ZNeEVWOUczVEU/1361561848_01%20-%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F.jpg)). Какой здесь использован view?

Comment: мне почему то кажется, что это кастомизированный ViewPager

Comment: Ссылка на пример не работает, не возможно понять какой вид должно иметь меню. Можете ли добавить скрины?

Answer (score 2):

Извиняюсь, что не полный ответ, но думаю, сами разберетесь...  
То, что вам нужно, можно найти [так](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android%20carousel%20view)